# How can I access another xml layout in MainActivity Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

**In my second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/userProfile"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
        android:text="Default Name"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**In my onCreate method in MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second, null, false);
        TextView myNameSample = view.findViewById(R.id.myName);
        myNameSample .setText("Mike");
        Toast.makeText(this, myNameSample .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The problem is it will not change current text "Default Name", but when you look at the toast message it will show the new name "Mike"

Comment: You're not actually associating the second layout with the activity. How would the Activity understand that you are trying to display the layout, and aren't just generating a bunch of java objects?

Comment: I don't want to display the layout, I just need to get the id and change the text in the second xml.

Comment: With the `setText` method you have changed the value from "Default Name" to "Mike". This is what you appear to be trying to achieve and you have demonstrated this has worked via the `Toast`. What isn't working?

Comment: It will only show in toast message but in the actual text it will remain the same as "Default Name"

Comment: By the "actual text" do you mean within the xml file? Are you trying to mutate the xml file at runtime? This is not a typical feature of Android.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to change the default text by the user name when they are login because the second xml file is a header in the app bar and this is the place where I want to change the default text by the user name. Is there a way on how I can achieve that?

Comment: I think you need to post the main layout code, so that we can see how these things are connected.